# Wiki API unable to parse JSON

Tags: json, api, search, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to access Wiki api with below query:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=india&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=5&origin=*&prop=extracts&exchars=200&exlimit=max&explaintext=1&exintro=1`

I'm getting response, but when I'm using `JSON.parse` to parse response Mozilla is displaying an error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: What is the response that you're getting from Wiki? Try printing it without parsing

Comment: Yes, I did. I validated response using JSON validator and no error found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=india&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=5&origin=*&prop=extracts&exchars=200&exlimit=max&explaintext=1&exintro=1&format=json`

Add the `format=json` query parameter. Otherwise you're getting HTML with embedded JSON

Comment: Orphid ! Now URL seems perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add finally format JSON string in url

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=india&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=5&origin=%2A&prop=extracts&exchars=200&exlimit=max&explaintext=1&exintro=1&format=json